# Code to do ANOVA on different Dataframes where groups can change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, anova

I have the following Dataframe. However it could be any data frame in that format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': [4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.5,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14,4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69,6.31,5.12,5.54,5.5,5.37,5.29,4.92,6.15,5.8,5.26],
                   'Group': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'] 
                   })
```

How can I perform an ANOVA to give me the F and p values for this *without* explicitly specifying the groups by text? In other words, is there a code that will automatically detect the groups and run an ANOVA so that it will work on any dataframe in that structure, not just this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the similarity of the means between each combinations of groups, we can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`scipy.stats.f_oneway`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html):

The `null hypothesis` here is, as quoted from the documentation:

> that two or more groups have the same population mean

---

#### Scenario 1: comparing all groups:

```
from scipy.stats import f_oneway

grps = [d['Weight'] for _, d in df.groupby('Group')]

F, p = f_oneway(*grps)

print(F, p)
4.846087862380136 0.0159099583256229
```

---

#### Scenario 2: comparing each combination of columns:

```
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.stats import f_oneway

combs = list(combinations(df['Group'].unique(), 2))
for g1, g2 in combs:
    a = f_oneway(df.loc[df['Group'] == g1, 'Weight'], 
                 df.loc[df['Group'] == g2, 'Weight'])
    print(f'For groups {g1} & {g2} the F-value is: {a[0]}, the p-value is: {a[1]}')
```

**Output**

```
For groups A & B the F-value is: 1.4191012973623165, the p-value is: 0.24902316597300575
For groups A & C the F-value is: 4.554043294351827, the p-value is: 0.04685138491157386
For groups B & C the F-value is: 9.0606932332992, the p-value is: 0.007518426118219876
```

Comment: Is there are way to use
  
`from scipy import stats

F, p = stats.f_oneway(d_data['ctrl'], d_data['trt1'], d_data['trt2'])`  
But with code specifying the groups. I wish to compare all the groups rather than one with the other

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. I will add code to compare all groups at once.

Comment: Correct. Im just trying to be able to find a way to add parameters in stats.f_oneway to compare them all and give a F and p value. But have the code work for any size of groups as there is already an example on the link you gave me if you want to specify the parameters.

Comment: It is really weird, because `f_onway` does not accept a list of lists. only seperate lists.

Comment: I know. I tried that and it didnt work :(. To add more context, I have engagement score for each person. And also demographic details of each person like gender, age group, location etc. It would be a pain to redo the code for each demographic. Im trying to find a code that automatically picks up the groups (gender will pick up Male, Female) for example. This will allow me to re run it over every demographic rather than edit the code for each one.

Comment: I see, yes thats frustrating, I posted an [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11807) about this on GitHub, will keep you updated here.

Comment: Found the solution, we just had to use the start (`*`) operator. I guess I had a brain freeze @Mish . See edit of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211069/discussion-between-erfan-and-mish).